# How to write to file from char[][]?

Tags: c, arrays, segmentation-fault, fputs

I am gathering data into a char[][] array, then let a user choose which of those string to write to a file. So I'm doing for example

```
char arr[3][3]; // assume there are three different two-char long strings in there
FILE* f = fopen("file", "w");
fputs(arr[1], f);
fclose(f);
```

Now the problem is, I'm getting a segfault on the `fputs()` call and I dont know why.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Have you checked the file pointer returned by `fopen` to make sure it isn't NULL?  Assuming `arr` contains 3 two-character long strings, that's the only thing I can think of that would cause `fputs` to barf.

Comment: @John Bode please put it in an answer so i can accept it. I didn't think of missing permissions on the file at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure the file pointer returned by `fopen` isn't NULL; assuming `arr` contains valid 0-terminated strings, that's the only other thing I can think of that would cause `fputs` to barf.

Answer (score 1):

1. `fputs` expects `\0`-terminated string. Make sure you add `0` in the end of the string that you supply there. Alternatively use `fwrite`.
2. check that `f != NULL` after `fopen`

Comment: Okay sorry, my strings are zero-terminated. I didn't think that was important.

Comment: @Cobra_Fast: I still suggest to use `fwrite`, it's better than fputs in this case. Can you please show how do u fill the array?

Comment: NULL terminating string?? '\0' terminating string!!

Answer (score 0):

What is arr pointing to? I guess the problem is due to arr not being initialized.

Comment: `arr` doesn't point to anything, it's an array. But you're right that in the example code it isn't initialized.

Comment: Please read the entire code, I wrote to assume that theres stuff in it.

Answer (score 0):

The char array pointed to by `arr[1]` is probably not null-terminated. You should declare `arr` as `char arr[3][4];` and fill the last column with `'\0'` (null) characters.

Answer (score 0):

May be you should check for the value returned by the file pointer!

Comment: Oppz sorry I got his question wrong I later on understood well I was sorta thinking he wants a character sorry for the wrong answer! well if my answer totally wrong?

Comment: okay im changing my code well I dont know that you can use 2 dimensional array in that way so i thought it might be wrong